# UIStackView height, content inside in the middle not at top

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a UIStackview, and when its filled with a bunch of things, its fine, However, when its filled with 1, or 2 (for example), it spreads them out and not keeps them at top. What did I do wrong?

[image]

This is what happens. I want them to be at the top and with No right under it.
[image]

```
for i in 0..<self.itemSpecificsArray.count {
                    let itemSpecificName = UILabel()
                    let itemSpecificValue = UILabel()

                    itemSpecificName.textColor = UIColor(red: 236.0 / 255.0, green: 91.0 / 255.0, blue: 110.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                    itemSpecificName.textAlignment = .left
                    itemSpecificName.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)

                    itemSpecificValue.textColor = UIColor.black
                    itemSpecificValue.textAlignment = .left
                    itemSpecificValue.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)

                    print(self.itemSpecificsArray[i].itemSpecificName)
                    print("** \(self.itemSpecificsArray[i].itemSpecificValue)")
                    itemSpecificName.text = self.itemSpecificsArray[i].itemSpecificName
                    itemSpecificValue.text = self.itemSpecificsArray[i].itemSpecificValue

                    self.mainSectionItemSpecifics.addArrangedSubview(itemSpecificName)
                    self.mainSectionItemSpecifics.addArrangedSubview(itemSpecificValue)
                     if (i == self.itemSpecificsArray.count) {
                        let view = UIView()
                        self.mainSectionItemSpecifics.addArrangedSubview(view)
                    }
                }
```

For each index, it has a itemSpecificName and itemSpecificValue. If I need to put these two Labels inside of a View, then I can do that...That will probably fix it, wouldnt it?

Comment: I think you forgot to specify height for every view which placed inside your UIStackView, but maybe I am wrong, so if you share with me your `Storyboard` it would easier to me to say exactly what is the problem.

Comment: Those views are added programmically.

Comment: @Andrew i added the *ugly* code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIStackView` wants to stretch its arranged subviews to fill its own (the stack view's) bounds. If you don't want the labels stretched, you either need to change the constraints on the `UIStackView` so that it can shrink to fit its children, or add an arranged subview to the stack view that can absorb the extract space. For example, you can add a plain `UIView` with no constraints after the two labels. Auto layout will give the extra space of the stack view's bounds to the `UIView`.

Comment: I added the extra UIView and that didnt do the trick. I added the code above.

Comment: Thanks man, i realized that I have to do the count of the array minus 1.